# How to "install" a C library

Tags: c, windows, codeblocks

I'm trying to use the Prime Sieve library (found [here](http://primesieve.org/)) in one of my C programs. However, i'm having a hard time "installing" the library.

I'm currently using the Code::block's IDE and following the guide [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/).

However, when trying to link the `.lib` files, I found that the zip file I had downloaded did not contain any. So, I figured that I needed to "make" the library first. When running `mingw32-make` I get the message that "nothing needs to be done".

Not sure what to do next ...

Edit: I should probably mention that I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Try `mingw32-make` instead. That is, without the `Makefile` arg as that tells make to build `Makefile` which is clearly not what you want.

Comment: If you downloaded the sourcecode you have to run `./configure` first

Comment: @deamentiaemundi I am on Windows 10. I don't think we have that command.

Comment: @kaylum I get `mingw32-make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`

Comment: As pointed out you need to run `configure`. That is a script that comes with the library. I suggest you read the [library's build instructions](https://github.com/kimwalisch/primesieve#build-requirements)

Comment: @kaylum Thanks but I did already read through that. The part containing configure is listed under (unix-like OS's) and I am on Windows 10. The only instructions for Windows is for Visual C++ which I am also not using :(

Comment: But you are using a Unix-like OS/environment. That is what mingw provides for you. Whether it will actually work or not with mingw is another matter. But you need to at least try those instructions.

Comment: @kaylum The `./configure` command does not work.

Comment: And did you run `autogen.sh`? If it doesn't work then we can't really help you here because you may be in an environment that the library author does not support. Making that work under such a circumstance would be too broad for an SO question.

Comment: Here's  somebody who succesfully tried to compile another lib with the same problem as you https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ppp-public/CuTWEfUcPiw

Comment: Do you also have MSYS installed? `configure` is a shell script, you need to run it within a POSIX compliant shell.

Comment: There are two options.  1) you could try to use the instructions for Visual C++ (you would have to make some changes possibly) or 2) you could install Cygwin or MSYS to get a unix like sub-system but you really don't need to - Windows 10 comes with a copy of Ubuntu's userspace (including bash) which you can install under Add and Remove Features (instructions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XUjktkGzlMg )

Comment: I used MSYS and it seems to work but now I cannot link it!

Comment: @MathMajor, should it be possible to post some code?  Are you making a normal static linking library? a shared library? What operating system are you trying to install it to?  Do you have source code? where is it?